# How would I return a value from a button that is clicked on? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Sorry about the vague question found it hard to phrase. Anyway I am making a website for a Toy Store. My problem is that for every type of toy whether it may be board games, Lego or action figures etc. I don't want to make separate pages for every genre. I want to make a dynamic page that the buttons would all link to. So the page knows what button was pressed and can begin querying the database from the button they pressed.

To summarize if they were to select Lego then it would go to the product listing page. But if they were to select Board games it would also go to the product listing page but both buttons would yield different results.

I am using C#, ASP.NET with Bootsrap.

Thanks.

Code for reference:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Toys <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Lego</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Board Games</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I think your question is too generic, this is about your web site architecture, not about specific code. However, don't do that, use links like: /toys/building/lego.html using RewriteRule to route all the pages on one aspx page this way you get a good indexing on search engines.

Comment: It is about specific code, below is an example of a button I would use:
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
In the href what would I put so that it would send a query to the server? Or am I supposed to use something else?

Comment: It's not about code, otherwise just write /whatever inside each href. The question here is how would you deal the urls, how would you parse the parameters? Do you see what I mean? There's no a universal-right-agnostic url for pages, it depends how the site is build. For example, are you using WebForms or MVC? That changes all.

Comment: I see what you mean, I just want to parse the parameters through the URL. Could I do for example <li><a href="ListingPage.aspx?selection=Lego">Lego</a></li>. Then on the server have a request.querystring? I am using WebForms.

Comment: Yes, exactly you could do that, except it's quite obsolete, instead you Rewrite Rules http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module that transforms urls like /section/lego to ListingPage.aspx?selection=Lego

Comment: Thank You! Can't believe its this simple. Sorry if it seemed vague had no idea what terminology to use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [passing values between pages in asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).

You just need to create page and pass the product type as an argument and use that to query your db.

Comment: But what do I write in the markup? So that it actually sends a value to the server so that it can use the value to create the page? Most of this is server side stuff and not markup. Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your hyperlinks to asp LinkButton controls like this:

```
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Lego" 
           OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton2" 
           Text="Board Games" 
           OnClick="LinkButton2_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
</li>
```

And then in your code behind, perform different actions for the different buttons:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("You clicked Lego");
}


protected void LinkButton2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("You clicked Board Games");
}
```